# Напишите функцию, которая принимает строку. Возвращает строку, содержащую все символы исх стр, все буквы в верхнем регистре должны быть в нижнем

Tags: java

Напишите функцию, которая принимает строку. Возвращает строку, содержащую все символы исходной строки, но все буквы в верхнем регистре должны быть в нижнем регистре. Строка может содержать символы с кодами от 32 по 126.

Написала код, но скорее всего напутала с типами переменных
Пожалуйста помогите исправить ошибку
Вот мой код

```
public static String toLowerCase(String s){
        char [] array = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            char a = 0;
            if (array[i] >= 65 && array[i] <= 90){
                a = (char)(array[i] + 32);
            }else{
                a = (char)(array[i]);
            }
        }
        String result = new String(array);
        return result;
    }
```

После того как я в for создала переменную для последующего присвоения, я пробовала возвращать return полученное значение:  "return a" -  но выделяет красным, ругается что разные типы... Может кто-то подскажет как правильно написать.... Заранее огромное спасибо...

Comment: Я не джавист, но во-первых после получения нового символа значение `a` у вас никуда не присваивается, а значит оно просто пропадает. Как минимум после конструкции if-else в цикле нужно присвоить значение `a` текущему элементу массива `array[i] = a;`.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Да Ваш ответ мне помог  - задача решена верно!!!! Премного благодарна !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, как правильно написал @rusgeli - у вас переменной a ничего не присваивалось.
Чтобы не забывать об этом, стоит переменные (даже временные) именовать явно, чтобы было понимание, что за данные в них лежат.

Ну, скажем, не:

```
    a = (char)(array[i]);
```

а что-то вроде:

```
    newChar = (char)(array[i]);
```

и тогда можно обратить внимание, что newChar есть, но с ним никто ничего не делает.)

В Вашем случае и вовсе можно написать что-то подобное, без переменной:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if (array[i] >= 65 && array[i] <= 90){
                array[i] = (char)(array[i] + 32);
            }
        }
```

Как понимаете, else Вам не сильно нужен.)

А вот на разные типы компилятор ругался, потому что в сигнатуре метода вы пишете "String", что предполагает, что метод вернет значение типа String.
Но когда пишете "return a" - возвращаете char, ведь именно этот тип Вы указали переменной.

А вот return result - уже верно, т.к. присвоено корректное значение.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения))) Ваша информация полезна...